# JSON string with multiple tables

Tags: json

I'm calling a web service that returns a JSON string containing multiple table objects from a DataSet.  I've tried countless options and haven't been able to access the JSON array in my success function.  In the ajax call, data.d returns a string and data.d.Table returns undefined.  The JSON string validates.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm fairly new to JSON.

JSON string:

```
{"d":"{\"Table\":[{\"PID_Key\":1379391,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Alemao, Francisco | 3024250\"},{\"PID_Key\":1405973,\"EMP_NAME\":\"De Michieli, Francis | 3024570\"},{\"PID_Key\":1143321,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Ferris, Nick | 3024340\"},{\"PID_Key\":1557903,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Frison, Monika | 3024938\"},{\"PID_Key\":1220009,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Hand, Niccoli | 3024358\"},{\"PID_Key\":1592556,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Kearns, Ronald | 3024183\"},{\"PID_Key\":1552113,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Kurcz, Krystal | 3024911\"},{\"PID_Key\":1637525,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Leasure, Katherine | 3024100\"},{\"PID_Key\":1637274,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Myers, Lynn | 3024106\"},{\"PID_Key\":1418148,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Olson, Amy | 3024663\"},{\"PID_Key\":1368903,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Rosemond, Courtniegh | 3024110\"},{\"PID_Key\":1637715,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Sims, Jeryka | 3024108\"},{\"PID_Key\":1637610,\"EMP_NAME\":\"Wilder, Ashley | 3024097\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"ExceptCode\":\"BRKHR\",\"Description\":\"BRKHR - Approved Paid HR Break\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"COACH\",\"Description\":\"COACH - Coachings, 1 on 1s, and reviews\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"MEET\",\"Description\":\"MEET - All Meetings\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"MEETOFFS\",\"Description\":\"MEETOFFS - Meeting at Offsite Location\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"PROJ\",\"Description\":\"PROJ - SME, POC, and all other projects\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"PROJOFFS\",\"Description\":\"PROJOFFS - Project at Offsite Location\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"PROTIME\",\"Description\":\"PROTIME - SavePro – For SavePro Huddles and Coaching Only\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"SYSTEM\",\"Description\":\"SYSTEM - Systems issues\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"TRAIN\",\"Description\":\"TRAIN - Training Exception (not CBT)\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"TRAIN_CBT\",\"Description\":\"TRAIN_CBT - Computer Based Training\"},{\"ExceptCode\":\"TRAINOFFS\",\"Description\":\"TRAINOFFS - Train at Offsite Location\"}],\"Table2\":[{\"Dept\":\"1\"}]}"}
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ExceptionServices.asmx/GetAgentsCodes',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"supPidKey":"' + supPidKey + '" }',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
            alert(data.d.Table);
            $.each(data.d.Table, function (PID_Key, val) {
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

C#:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetAgentsCodes(int supPidKey)
    {
        classes.ExceptionObject excObj = new classes.ExceptionObject();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(JsonMethods.ToJson(excObj.getAgentsCodes(supPidKey)));
    }

public static Dictionary<string, object> ToJson(DataSet data)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataTable table in data.Tables)
            {
                d.Add(table.TableName, RowsToDictionary(table));
            }
            return d;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar issue....  I answered my own question.  Needed to parse the data returned in my success function before accessing it.

```
success: function (data) {
            var parsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            $.each(parsed.Table, function (i, val) {
                alert(val.PID_Key);
            });
        },
```